# VBA Excel Printing data into Immediate Window about a range data to test understanding

Tags: excel, output, range, vba

I am wanting to do a series of small tests that helps builds my understand as I work around a small business problem of generating data in the correct manner.

My first approach is to prove for myself that I could Print (string data type) a list of ID's (using the .value method) in the Immediate window of the VBE so I can see the list which I can then build up another test afterwards.

My VBA code at the moment shows this which I define "CustTest" as a named Range from A1:A100 in Sheet 1

```
Sub TestRanges()

Dim Custrng As Range

For Each Custrng In Range("CustTest")
    Print Custrng.Value
Next
End Sub
```

I also thought of this

```
Sub TestRanges()

Dim Custrng As Range

For Each Custrng In Range("CustTest")
    With Custrng
       Print  .Value
    End With
Next
End Sub
```

This came up with an error I am not sure what has occured, Compile Error:-  Method not valid without suitable object.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Peter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use: `Debug.Print .Value` instead of `Print .Value`

**Additional information:** `Print` is suitable to use only in Immediate window. However, we could use `?` (question mark) there instead of `Print`